# how to create a dataframe directly from groupby

Tags: python, pandas

My code beneath works fine. But... I think there is a more efficient way of coding this. But I can't figure it out. I thought reset_index() worked well, but it doesn't in this case.
So, all suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance!

I have a large dataframe (hospital data). All data are from 2017, 2018 and 2019.
The column: spoedelectief can have two values: one for emergency and one for non emergency patient.
In Dutch emergency is called Spoed. So, emergency is S and non emergency is E.

From the dataframe I want to make ( to visualize the amount of emergency and non emergency each year) a new dataframe. But I'm stuck with that. Some code;

```
test = df_new.groupby(df_new['operatiejaar'])['spoedelectief'].value_counts().sort_index()
```

gives back a Pandas Series:

```
operatiejaar  spoedelectief
2017          E                5459
              S                1054
2018          E                6191
              S                1029
2019          E                6160
              S                1159
```

For visualisation in Seaborn I tried to make this a DataFrame with reset_index() but that gives an error:

> ValueError: cannot insert spoedelectief, already exists

Making test a DataFrame works:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(test)
```

With this result:

[image]

But test.columns gives this:

```
Index(['spoedelectief'], dtype='object')
```

Underneath the code I used to create a DataFrame as I wanted:

```
test = df_new.groupby(df_new['operatiejaar'])['spoedelectief'].value_counts().sort_index()

jaar_list = []
spel_list = []
totaal = []
for index, value in test.items():
    jaar_list.append(index[0])
    spel_list.append(index[1])
    totaal.append(value)

spel_jaar = pd.DataFrame(
    {'jaar': jaar_list,
     'spoedelectief': spel_list,
     'totaal': totaal
    })
```

Which gives the desired DF:

[image]

How to code this much easier / directly from the original DF? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `rename` Series before [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
test = (df_new.groupby(df_new['operatiejaar'])['spoedelectief']
              .value_counts()
              .rename('count')
              .sort_index()
              .reset_index())
```

Or use `name` in [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
test = (df_new.groupby(df_new['operatiejaar'])['spoedelectief']
              .value_counts()
              .sort_index()
              .reset_index(name='count'))
```

Comment: no need to repeat `df_new` in the arg of `groupby`, and no need for `sort_index` either.

Answer (score 1):

Two additional options to consider:

1. [`Series.to_frame(name)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html):

   ```
   test = (
       df_new.groupby('operatiejaar')['spoedelectief']
       .value_counts().to_frame('totaal').reset_index()
   )
   ```
2. Reshape your result into several columns, one for each name found by `value_counts`:

   You can also avoid naming the series and instead expand it into two columns for nicer plotting:

   ```
   # 'E' and 'S' counts become two columns
   test2 = (
       df_new.groupby('operatiejaar')['spoedelectief']
       .value_counts().unstack()
   )
   test2.plot.bar()
   ```

   Example (on small randomly generated data):

   [image]

**Notes**:

- You can dispense with `df_new[column_name]` as argument for the `groupby`, and just specify `column_name`.
- You don't have to `sort_index()` (at least with recent versions of Pandas): both `groupby()` and `value_counts()` sort by default.

Comment: Pierre thanks! great and helpfull answer also. cheers Jan